# Show and hide different contents with angularjs ng-show / ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I am new with angularjs and struggling to make some logic for Showing and hiding different Div's using ng-show and ng-hide based on different click.

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqSaY4GfLFHCzXzmXU7B?p=preview)**

**View 1:**

```
<div ng-hide="section1">
  <select>
    <option>Select List 1</option>
    <option>Select List 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div ng-hide="section1">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name.item}}</li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" ng-click="section1=!section1">Edit</button>
</div>
```

Initially it shows a Dropdown, some list Item and Edit button

Clicking on Edit button Everything hides and shows View 2

**View 2:**

```
<div ng-show="section1">
       <button type="button" ng-click="section2=!section2">+ Create New Item</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="section1">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names">
          <input type="text" ng-model="name.item">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" ng-click="section1=!section1">Save</button>
    </div>
```

On view 2 There is a button "Create New item" , List of Input fields with same value of view 1's list items and a save button.
This view 2 is basically edit mode of view 1.

Upto now works fine.

**Problem**: If I click "+Create new item", "View 2" Should Hide and "View 3" should Open.

View 3 Contains some blank input list and "Save button".Clicking on "save button" Hide "View 3" and again open "View 1".

**View 3**

```
<div ng-show="section2">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names">
          <input type="text">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" ng-click="section2=!section2">Save New List</button>
    </div>
```

I am struggling to manage 3 different view based on different button click with ng-show and Hide. It's not showing and hiding properly from clicking "+create new button".

Is this possible to make it work perfectly with ng-show & ng-hide only ? 
Is there any better way to handle ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to handle what you're trying to do is to have a variable that holds the index of the current section. Then, you could use something like `ng-show="currentSection === 1"` which I think would be a little more straight forward.

Then your click action could look more like `ng-click="currentSection = 1"`. That will show all elements with `ng-show="currentSection === 1"`.

Does that help any?

Comment: I thought on the same solution but I've been to slow ;) . Here is a Plucker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gu1MediofPL2eEuWXpez?p=preview

Comment: Any Example will really help  more. Also thanks for the answer :) @arjabbar

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your plunker to fix your issue. You need to use both variable in ng-show

```
ng-show="section1 && !section2"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rdKIT4leGM9U7BNoE01B?p=preview

There are better ways to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Try ng-switch for example

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) . This will work fine for me. 
If you can do one  favor of creating/editing this with ng-switch will be great help.

Comment: You should try to make a first attempt to do that yourself. If you cannot get it working, post another question and myself and others will help